# Create multiple batch files from a text file

Tags: batch-file

I'm working on a project and I need to create multiple batch files from a text file.
Meaning that, I want to run a script that will loop into a test.txt that contains multiple IPs. I want create a batch file for every IP in that list.
The end result will be that I will use START to loop through newly created batch files so I can have multiple instances that run at the same time.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you gotten any code for us? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi Tom, unfortunately no. I am new to this. I searched this site for all possible solutions and could not find any that could be used in my case.

Comment: If possible try to create some code of your own first. We can point you in the right direction from there. This site isn't to ask for code but rather helping you modify your code to be better or resolve issues with it.

Comment: You probably want to look at [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Comment: I understand. Just wanted to have a base from what to start on my own with this code. If I manage to create something I will reply to this thread. Thanks for your fast replies.

Comment: With those three you can retrieve the resources from a file. `Explode` turns them into an array based on a delimiter. In this case you can use the new line as delimiter. And then turn each of the array elements into a new .bat file with `file_put_contents`.

Comment: If you have something and you get stuck with it. Edit your first post. Since that will remain as the question. Asking a good question and providing some code for SO. Will attract more people willing to help you! Help us help you.

Comment: Isn't it possible to do this only in batch? I don't have any knowledge about other programming languages.

Comment: Oh my. Sorry for some reason I thought the PHP tag was included. I'm sure it's possible in batch. Just try to make some code of your own first.

Comment: A snippet of your test.txt, and from the excepted Output(s).

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want each script to do the same thing, only with a different IP address each time. Creating a separate batch script for each IP address is totally  unnecessary - you simply need one script that takes the IP address as a parameter. Assuming the IP address is the first parameter, then it would be referenced using `%1`. Here is a trivial demo - obviously you would modify processIP.bat to do what you want with the IP address.

**main.bat**

```
@echo off
for /f %%A in (test.txt) do start "" processIP %%A
```

**processIP.bat**

```
@echo off
echo Processing %1 to demonstrate how to access the IP parameter
pause
```

You could even combine everything into one script. `%~f0` expands to the full path of the currently running batch script, so the script knows how to call itself, no matter where it is located or what name it has. You simply pass an extra parameter with a specific value to indicate which code to execute.

**anyname.bat**

```
@echo off
if %1==:processIP (
  shift /1
  goto :processIP
)

for /f %%A in (test.txt) do start "" "%~f0" :processIP %%A
exit /b

:processIP
echo Processing %1 to demonstrate how to access the IP parameter
pause
```

Certainly you can have a batch script dynamically create and call a new batch script on the fly, but usually there is a better way to accomplish the task at hand.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem. In the mean time i figured out how to create individual batch files but your way is much more clean.